# RequireJS plugin( order.js )

Tags: javascript, requirejs

http://requirejs.org/

I recently downloaded require.js 2.0 and I am getting error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){var g=ga.call(arguments,0),e;if(f&&v(e=g[g.length-1]))e.__requireJsBuild=!0;g.push(d);return b.apply(null,g)} has no method 'nameToUrl'
```

Is order.js plugin still supported by requirejs? I don't see its documentation in the website.

When I try to remove the file the script breaks.

In my index file, I included requirejs script in the head section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            My Mobile Application
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/style.css" />
        <script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Then in my main.js file:

```
requirejs.config({
    //By default load any module IDs from js/lib
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    //except, if the module ID starts with "app",
    //load it from the js/app directory. paths
    //config is relative to the baseUrl, and
    //never includes a ".js" extension since
    //the paths config could be for a directory.
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        assets: '../assets',
        views: '../app/views',
        templates: '../app/templates',
        collections: '../app/collections',
        models: '../app/models'
    }
});

// Start the main app logic.
requirejs([
    'jquery/jquery',
    'assets/jqm.config',
    'jquery/mobile',
    'text'
]);

require([
    'app'
    ],
    function( App ){
        $(document).ready( function(){
            App.initialize();
        });
    }
);
```

I sees to it that App.initialize doesn't have any errors and what App.initialize is doing is just simple geo location. The requirejs simply ask for order.js, and when I put the code it's having the same error as mentioned above.

Thank you!

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/177538). What's the code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your assumption that `order` is no longer supported is correct. It was removed in favour of the `shim` configuration option:

> So, the the order plugin has been removed and following the lead of
>   Tim Branyen and Dave Geddes, of use and wrap respectively, requirejs
>   2.0 integrates that kind of dependency tree specification directly in requirejs.

Require 2.0 upgrade notes - https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0

Also, check the `shim` documentation on the RequireJS site - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, that's was a great help indeed. Will try it now and let you know if it is working :)

Comment: I am using jQuery by the way and earlier I downloaded [link](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#samplejquery) a file from the given link, I used it's require-jquery.js instead of require.js, now I am receiving this error: plugin is undefined. Its very hard to debug the kinds errors.

Comment: In chrome's inspect element, I am receiving this error:  Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined . Sigh*

Comment: very useful, didn't know about shim so far!

Answer (score 2):

Oh figured it out.

```
//This is our main applicatoon boot loader or bootstrap
//here we are loading necessary scripts dependencies like
//jquery, jqm.config, mobile, text


requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/libs',
    //except, if the module ID starts with "app",
    //load it from the js/app directory. paths
    //config is relative to the baseUrl, and
    //never includes a ".js" extension since
    //the paths config could be for a directory.
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        assets: '../assets',
        views: '../app/views',
        templates: '../app/templates',
        collections: '../app/collections',
        models: '../app/models'
    }
});

// Start the main app logic.

require(["jquery","assets/jqm.config","jquery/mobile","text","app"], 
    function(
    $,
    config,
    mobile,
    text,
    App
    ) {
    //the jquery.alpha.js and jquery.beta.js plugins have been loaded.
    $(function() {
        App.initialize();
    });
});
```