# requirejs load stuff in order

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm confused about requirejs 2.0. Before I was using the !order tag, but now the javascripts don't load in order (unless I run optimize). Apparently the orderjs support was removed

If I have 5 scripts, and I need the first three to load in order, how would I use this with the  `shim` ?

Before I was doing

```
require([
    "order!libraries/file1",
    "order!libraries/file2",
    "order!includes/file3",
    "libraries/file4",
    "libraries/file5"
],
function(){
console.log("All done. Everything loaded. Now we can start the app");
});
```

How do I translate this now to requirejs 2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10842492/1217408

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    file1: 'libraries/file1',
    file2: 'libraries/file2',
    file3: 'libraries/file3',
    file4: 'libraries/file4',
    file5: 'libraries/file5'
  },
  shim: {
    'file2': ['file1'],
    'file3': ['file2']
  }
});

require([
    "file1",
    "file2",
    "file3",
    "file4",
    "file5"
],
function(){
  console.log("All done. Everything loaded. Now we can start the app");
});
```